# groupby cumsum (or cumcount) with cyclical data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like

| ID | SWITCH |
| --- | --- |
| A | ON |
| A | ON |
| A | ON |
| A | OFF |
| A | OFF |
| A | OFF |
| A | ON |
| A | ON |
| A | ON |
| ... | ... |
| B | ON |
| B | ON |
| B | ON |
| B | OFF |
| B | OFF |
| B | OFF |
| B | ON |
| B | ON |
| B | ON |

Column 'SWITCH' is cyclical data and I'd like to count the number of ON and OFF for each cycle like this:

| ID | SWITCH | Cum. Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | ON | 1 |
| A | ON | 2 |
| A | ON | 3 |
| A | OFF | 1 |
| A | OFF | 2 |
| A | OFF | 3 |
| A | ON | 1 |
| A | ON | 2 |
| A | ON | 3 |
| ... | ... |  |
| B | ON | 1 |
| B | ON | 2 |
| B | OFF | 1 |
| B | OFF | 2 |
| B | OFF | 3 |
| B | ON | 1 |
| B | ON | 2 |
| B | ON | 3 |

I'd tried `cumsum` or `cumcount` but it didn't reset the count when the next 'ON' cycle has come (it keeps counting on the number from the previous cycle).

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new column which indicates the change in the 'SWITCH' column, then you can use 'groupby' to perform the cumulative count.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A'] * 9 + ['B'] * 9,
                   'SWITCH': ['ON'] * 3 + ['OFF'] * 3 + ['ON'] * 3 + ['ON'] * 3 + ['OFF'] * 3 + ['OFF'] * 3})

df['SWITCH_CHANGE'] = (df['SWITCH'] != df['SWITCH'].shift()).astype(int)

df['Cum. Count'] = df.groupby(['ID', df.SWITCH_CHANGE.cumsum()])['SWITCH'].cumcount() + 1

print(df)
```

Result:

| ID SWITCH | SWITCH_CHANGE | Cum. Count |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | ON | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | A | ON | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | A | ON | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | A | OFF | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | A | OFF | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | A | OFF | 0 | 3 |
| 6 | A | ON | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | A | ON | 0 | 2 |
| 8 | A | ON | 0 | 3 |
| 9 | B | ON | 0 | 1 |
| 10 | B | ON | 0 | 2 |
| 11 | B | ON | 0 | 3 |
| 12 | B | OFF | 1 | 1 |
| 13 | B | OFF | 0 | 2 |
| 14 | B | OFF | 0 | 3 |
| 15 | B | OFF | 0 | 4 |
| 16 | B | OFF | 0 | 5 |
| 17 | B | OFF | 0 | 6 |

Answer (score 1):

Try put in the cumsum of the difference as well:

```
switch_blocsk = df['SWITCH'].ne(df['SWITCH'].shift()).cumsum()

df['cum.count'] = df.groupby(['ID', switch_blocks]).cumcount().add(1)
```